# Why PPPoE Connection fails with error 691

Tags: networking, internet, connection, broadband, pppoe

I am using the same credential in another machine when creating a broadband connection. it's working in one machine. when i try it in other machine it gives me the connection error with 691?

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: 691 means “Access was denied because the user name and/or password was invalid on the domain." Either you have a typeo in the username or password, or there's an issue on the ISP side.

Comment: i am using the same credential in other machine it's working. so is there any problem with my drivers?? i have tried re-installing the driver still the same error. if it's a ISP problem it shouldn't work in other machine also.

Comment: May be your ISP has deployed MAC Address Authentication in addition to username and password and first machine's LAN MAC Address is registered with the ISP. As a result the correct logon credentials work on the first machine but not the other.

Comment: I would agree along the lines of what Pat said. Rather than setting up the same credentials on a new machine, why not use a network switch?

Comment: Switch is also not working. i will take a call with ISP and let you know if it's Mac address Authentication thank you guys

Comment: @pat2015 perhaps you should transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: guys i found the solution ISP have mac address limit once it reached you can't connect new machines. i have called them then they have cleared the mac address for me. no i can connect it to other machines :)

Comment: ISP has fixed this issue at their end